# Adding multiple rows mysql in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute a rather complicated task in phpmyadmin.
Shortly i need to add multiple rows in a table that uses a certain value from another table column.
I kinda figured out how to add 1 row manually) but since i need 11.000 of it..

```
INSERT INTO  `DATABASE`.`ratings` (
`id` ,
`total_votes` ,
`total_value` ,
`used_ips`
)
VALUES (
'5000',  '10',  '1000', NULL
);
```

There are 2 TABLES (CONTENT and RATINGS) in same DB.
In **CONTENT** there is a column named CONTENT_RECORD (11.000 entries) which excists of only numbers

In **RATINGS** we have 4 colums (ID,TOTAL_VOTES,TOTAL_VALUE,USED_IPS)
I want to add multiple rows in RATING with following values.

```
ID = should copy the value from table CONTENT, column CONTENT_RECORD

Total_votes = fixed number 10

Total_value = fixed number 1000

used_ips = leave empty
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use insert..into..select syntax. Something like this -

```
INSERT INTO `DATABASE`.`ratings`(`id`, `total_votes`, `total_value`, `used_ips`)
SELECT CONTENT_RECORD, '10', '1000', NULL FROM CONTENT
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. : )
There was a small issue with having duplicate content (it does not copy whenever there is a duplicate entry) but by deleting ID and re-run the command it all worked. 

thanks again

Answer (score -2):

insert into table_name
values('values of your table for row1'),('values of your table for row 2),..........('values of your table for row n

Comment: That's not what the author was asking for. Do you expect him typing out this 11,000 times?